# definePlugin is not working in react webpack.config.js in create-react-app boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to set a service URL for frontend according to the environment.

what I have tried till now.

```js
    const currentPath =  path.join(__dirname);
    const basePath =  currentPath +   ".env";
    const envPath = basePath +"."+ process.env.NODE_ENV;
    const finalPath = fs.existsSync(envPath) ? envPath : basePath;

    const fileEnv = dotenv.config({ path: finalPath }).parsed;
    let envKeys = Object.keys(fileEnv).reduce((prev, next) => {
        prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(fileEnv[next]);
        return prev;
        }, {});


//in the plugins array

new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys should not be stringified

```
    let envKeys = Object.keys(fileEnv).reduce((prev, next) => {
        prev.process.env[next] = JSON.stringify(fileEnv[next]);
        return prev;
    }, {process: {env: {}}});
```

Comment: @KrishnaKamal how did you check that? what is `fileEnv`? For example if your fileEnv is `{ PRODUCTION: true }` then in runtime `if (process.env.PRODUCTION) {}` should work.

Comment: `` if(process.env.DEVELOPMENT){
 console.log("development");
}``  and  in developement file ```{
 DEVELOPMENT: true,
 API_URI = `http://localhost:9000`
}```